# Docker for windows using WSL2 without moving files to distro drive to increase load time

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

With docker for windows loading my apps very slow, usually 6-10 seconds of GET/POST request from API to MySQL database (all in a docker container connected to a single network), I was able to improve its loading speed to less than a second.

Here's how I did it.

1. Download and install docker for windows
2. Download and install Ubuntu distro on the Microsoft Store (just search Ubuntu)
3. Set Ubuntu as the default WSL engine and make sure it is set to version 2 (mine was set to version 1 and I need to update it to use version 2)

[image]

4. Set Ubuntu in the WSL integration menu in docker. If you haven't install any distro yet, you won't find any listed here and default disto used will be "docker-desktop" (as shown on the image in Step 3)

[image]

Before using Ubuntu, here's my POST request via postman. (6 seconds for a simple select * from users)

[image]

After enabling Ubuntu WSL and moving my repo from Windows drive to WSL drive, here's the improvement in load time. (less than a second only!!!)

[image]

Huge performance increase!

Now the problem, is there a way to NOT move all my repositories from Windows drive to my WSL drive? I tried to bind it like so:

```
volumes:
    - /mnt/d/localhost/api/:/var/www/html
```

But loading time was just reduced to 50% (around 3 seconds)

[image]

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#best-practices) best practice note on Docker and the [official Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#performance-across-os-file-systems) regarding WSL2 and bind-mount performance?

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. Does that mean that there is no other way than to move all my repo files from my drive D to the WSL directory? I am working with 20+ repos and moving them and reconfiguring one by one will be cumbersome especially the need to execute `npm install`.